# How to stop a music and play again in Android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to write a simple Android MediaPlayer code. I am facing an issue while stopping a song and restart again. In each button click. Otherwise , if i wont stop the track then , in each button click the song is not playing , it wait until the songs stops.

My requirement is , in each button click the song should start from the beginning.

**MyCode:**

```
package com.example.musicexample;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   Button btnPlay;
   MediaPlayer mPlayer;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     btnPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);

     mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.a);

     btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
                mPlayer.reset();
            }

            mPlayer.start();
        }
    });
} }
```

In the above code , the song plays once then , it won't play again.

So please go through it , please let me know , how can i stop the track if the song is playing and then restart it from beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
MediaPlayer m1 = null;

        play1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        stopPlaying();
        m1=MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.a);
        m1.start();
        }
    });   

    private void stopPlaying() {
         if (mp1 != null) {
            m1.stop();
            m1.release();
            m1 = null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Once in the Stopped state, playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer object to the Prepared state again.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `reset()` method which returns the `MediaPlayer` to its un-initialized state.

> Resets the MediaPlayer to its uninitialized state.

You will have to set the source of the `MediaPlayer` once again to  get it to play.