# Multiple songs are playing in my audio player application

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have created an audio player application in android studio using list view which is working good but when I'm playing another song then previous one doesn't stop and keep playing.

```
package com.russvkm.audioplayer;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ListView listView;

   ArrayList<String> arrayList;

   ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);

        arrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);

        getSong();

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                stopPlaying();

                mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();

                playMedia(position);

            }
        });

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);

             }else{

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

            }
        }
    }

    public void getSong(){

        Uri uri= MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    

String selection=MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC;

    Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uri,null,selection,null,null);

    if(cursor!=null) {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){

            do {

                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));

                final String songUrl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

                final playerdata player = new playerdata(songUrl, name);

                arrayList.add(songUrl);

                listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

                cursor.close();

        }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode==1){

            if(grantResults.length>0&&grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    }

    public void playMedia(int number){

        String path = String.valueOf(listView.getItemAtPosition(number));

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if (mp != null) {
                            mp.start();

                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mediaplayer != null) {
            mediaplayer.stop();
            mediaplayer.release();
            mediaplayer = null
        }
}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop a music and play again in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28948968/how-to-stop-a-music-and-play-again-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop previous playing song before starting a new one

```
private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null
        }
}
```

So just call above method before playing a new song.

And once you playing a song initialize your player

```
mp=new MediaPlayer();
```

Comment: thank you for responding, i tried by this way but didn't work. will you exactly point me out that where i have to put the above method you mentioned cause i'm new to android development.

Comment: Call method before you calling playMedia() method.

Comment: Also don't forgot to initialize media player.

Comment: @shashank you can upvote and accept my answer so this will help others who facing same issue.

Comment: i have updated the code please visit that is it like so?

Comment: @Shashank i have checked your code it seems fine. Please run and let me know.

Comment: the problem has been resolved by your answer and it is working as i expected, millions thanks to you brother you make my day.

Comment: @Shashank you can always ask me any of your doubts.

Comment: You can find accept arrow and up vote button in the left of my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Implements onTrackChangeListener in yor Adapter